# Angular 9 - Get value Inside Observable Array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular5

I have an array of **servers** object where inside that array I have another observable array of objects, its key is **[securityGroups]**.

I have another array of **securitygroupsArray**, where I GET my API to fetch all **securityGroups**.

I need to look in my array of servers in the securityGroups key for all the names of the security group on that server, and show in an option only the names of the ngfor of my other array **(securityGroupArray)** that are different. I tried to use 3 ngFor, but it didn't work. Can you help me?

My Component code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin(
      this.serverService.getServer(),
      this.securityGroupService.getSecurityGroups())
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
      .subscribe(([servers, groups]) => {
        this.servers = servers.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          securityGroups: this.serverService.getServerById(item.id)
            .pipe(map(server => server["security_groups"]))
        }))
        this.securityGroupArray = groups['security_groups'].map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          expanded: false,
        }))
      }
```

My html code:

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select
        class="form-control border-primary"
        formControlName="server"
      >
        <option [value]="''">select</option>
        <span *ngFor="let group of securityGroupArray">
            <option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server.id">
              <span *ngFor="let secGroup of server.securityGroups | async">
                {{ secGroup.name !== group.name ? server.name : ''}}
              </span>
            </option>
        </span>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My servers array:

```
{id: "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e", name: "hello", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable} ,

{id: "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604", name: "test01", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable}
```

My securityGroupArray

```
{id: "b339774a-9ff7-4136-a0ca-94dd998b8dcc", name: "hello", description: "", …} ,

{id: "e96d271c-aa69-4a61-b0ca-63bfa8c1293e", name: "new09", description: "", …}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<span>` is not valid child of `<select>` use `<ng-container>` instead:

```html
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <select
      class="form-control border-primary"
      formControlName="server"
    >
      <option [value]="''">select</option>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let group of securityGroupArray">
          <option *ngFor="let server of servers" [value]="server.id">
            <span *ngFor="let secGroup of server.securityGroups | async">
              {{ secGroup.name !== group.name ? server.name : ''}}
            </span>
          </option>
      </ng-container>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

`<ng-container>` is a "virtual" DOM element; it will not be rendered to the actual DOM.

Comment: Hello. I tested this, and it actually revealed my items, but the result is incorrect. It shows all the names of the servers in my array, and not the servers.name of my logic. where I would like to show only server.name that
secGroup.name! == group.name.

I can't find where I'm going wrong. :/

Comment: Try an example of how you would like it to look, given some data

Comment: I tried to create a function and subscribe to my ['SecurityGroup'] key because it is an observable one and it didn't work. I honestly don't know where I'm going wrong: /

My code:

let secGroups: any[] = [];
    this.securityGroupsArray.map((group) => {
      this.servers.map(servers => {
        servers['securityGroups'].subscribe((server) => {
          server.map(sec => sec.name !== group.name && group.name !== 'default' ? secGroups.push(servers) : null)
        })
      })
    })
    return secGroups;

Comment: This won't work the observable will resolve after the array is created. The original solution is not bad, but a lot of info about your code is missing... what is the server returning, how are the 2 request related? And what you want to display. Show me something to work with...

Comment: About the relationship:

In my server array, I have the user's server information (servers array)

However, I need to know which security groups this machine uses. Then I make a request to (GetServerById) passing the server id, to create the * SecurityGroups * key within my server array. This code is in the question in my ngOnInit method.

In my html component, I have a button, which opens a modal, to attach a security group to a server, however, I need to show the user only the security groups that are not included in the server, that's why ngfor in select option.

Comment: To do this, I create a request for my securityGroups endpoint and create the securityGroupArray array.

The way to find out if the security group is attached to the user's server, is only by name. So I need to know if in my array of servers in the key security_groups * server ["security_groups"]. Name * is different from my securityGroupArray.name, if different, I can show this server in option, for the user to include this security group on your server.

Comment: This is the result of my array of servers after ngoninit and the securitygroups key was created dynamically.

{id: "1879f47f-1c5e-464b-bb76-e7cc13ef426e", name: "hello", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable},

{id: "b9c7e32a-bf99-4250-83cb-13523f9c1604", name: "test01", flavor: {…}, securityGroups: Observable}

The securityGroups key is an object array that contains the name key. 
like this:
securityGroups:
[{name: 'test1'}, {name: 'test2'}]

Comment: My securityGroupArray payload:
{id: "b339774a-9ff7-4136-a0ca-94dd998b8dcc", name: "hello", description: "", …} ,

{id: "e96d271c-aa69-4a61-b0ca-63bfa8c1293e", name: "new09", description: "", …}

Comment: It is way too confusing. Please edit the question; Add RAW HTML (not angular) you want as the result, I have some understanding of what the data from API looks like, but I can't wrap my head around what should be displayed.